# How many people do we need so that the probability of someone having the same birthday as Person A is 100%?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

> Suppose you have some designated Person A. How many people do we need so that the probability that one of those people has the same birthday as person A is 100%?

The first thing that came to my mind was $365$, but that doesn't have to be true. Some of those $365$ people could have the same birthday, so the Person A's birthday doesn't have to be covered. I thought of calculating probability that $n$ people don't share the birthday with Person A. Then $1$ minus that probability, I don't know how to calculate that. It seems to me that the probability I am asking for will never be 100%.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct.

Comment: To me that seems weird and kind of beautiful

Comment: If you have $367$ people, you can be certain that they do not all have different birthdays ($366$ if you ignore leap years) so some must share.  But you cannot be absolutely certain a particular person shares a birthday, even with more people, unless you have more information (such as them being in a room with their twin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct.

Given person $A$'s birthday, for each other person there is a probability of $364/365$ (ignoring leap years) that they do not share a birthday with $A$.

Therefore if there are $n$ others, then there is a probability of $(364/365)^n$ that none share a birthday with $A$, hence a probability of $1-(364/365)^n<1$ that at least one does share a birthday with $A$.

Comment: Thanks. The calculation wasnt hard but the result seemed weird to me so i thouht i was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can achieve a probability of 100% for this problem. Imagine that A is born on January 1st, but, being very unlucky, all the other persons are born on January 2nd.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct in saying that we can never get $100 $ percent  probability of having someone with the same birthday as person A.